# Yii2: не могу отключить CORS

Tags: php, yii2, cors

Сразу хочу сказать, что гуглил и пробовал разные варианты. А именно, через behaviors. Так же в index.php добавил такой код

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
```

Но ничего не помогает. Если в index.php просто вывести

```
echo 1;
```

выводится. Помогите, пол дня сегодня провозился

Answer (score 1):

в контроллер добавить

```
public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::class,
            'cors' => [
                // restrict access to
                'Origin' => ['*'],
           // Allow  methods
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', 'GET'],
                // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['Content-Type'],
                // Allow credentials (cookies, authorization headers, etc.) to be exposed to the browser
                //'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
                // Allow OPTIONS caching
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

еще можно так попробовать

```
public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: не помогает. вот так сейчас: https://pastebin.com/sPnyguHn

Comment: второе тоже в контроллер

Comment: не помогло, ошибка осталась